# Opening URL from select list and passing all variables on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a pretty basic form consisting of 3 elements – 2 text input boxes and a select drop-down list. What I’m looking to achieve when hitting the submit button is to open the page that is listed at the value for the drop-down option and also pass through the values/data entered into the 2 text boxes.
I can get the form to open the correct url from the selected drop-down item, however the two text inputs are not carried through to the opened page.

Can this be done? Any helps would be greatly be appreciated.

```
<p align="center">
<form method="POST" name="jump" class="center">

Start Time : <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" name="stime" SIZE="10" /><br>
End Time : <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" name="etime" SIZE="10" /><br>

    <select name="menu">
        <option value="#">Select a Device</option>
        <option value="rep-fire.php">Firewall</option>
        <option value="rep-wap.php">WAP</option>
        .....
    </select>
<input type="button" onClick="window.open(document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value);" value="GO">
</form>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [url.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and eventListeners

Note I changed name to ID

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.getElementById("jump").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    const path = document.getElementById("menu").value;
    if (path) {
      let url = new URL(location.href); 
      url.pathname = path;
      let parms = url.searchParams;
      parms.set("stime", document.getElementById("stime").value)
      parms.set("etime", document.getElementById("etime").value)
      console.log(url.toString());
      //    window.open(url.toString()); // uncomment when tested
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="jump" class="center">

  Start Time :
  <input type="text" id="stime" size="10" /><br> End Time :
  <input type="text" id="etime" size="10" /><br>

  <select id="menu">
    <option value="">Select a Device</option>
    <option value="rep-fire.php">Firewall</option>
    <option value="rep-wap.php">WAP</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```